# SQL select with unique_list - losing an item

Tags: oracle

I have an oracle database and I have the following problem:
If I make an select like this:

```
SELECT fk_proddes_id,fk_id_cod_deseu,
     LISTAGG (TO_CHAR (cod_eliminare), ',')
                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cod_eliminare)
     AS cod_eliminare
FROM sim_sd.proddes_ag_elim
GROUP BY fk_proddes_id, fk_id_cod_deseu
```

I get the following result:

```
FK_PRODDES_ID   FK_ID_COD_DESEU COD_ELIMINARE
53              112             D 11,D 11,D 7
301             506             D 1,D 15
```

I need the **unique code**, so if I put:

```
SELECT fk_proddes_id,fk_id_cod_deseu,
    unique_list ( LISTAGG (TO_CHAR (cod_eliminare), ',')
                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cod_eliminare))
     AS cod_eliminare
FROM sim_sd.proddes_ag_elim
GROUP BY fk_proddes_id, fk_id_cod_deseu
```

the result is:

```
FK_PRODDES_ID   FK_ID_COD_DESEU COD_ELIMINARE
53              112             D 11,D 7
301             506             D 15
```

so, I "lose" the D1 - don't know why...

If I put

```
SELECT fk_proddes_id,fk_id_cod_deseu,
    unique_list ( LISTAGG (TO_CHAR (cod_eliminare), ',')
                    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cod_eliminare DESC))
     AS cod_eliminare
FROM sim_sd.proddes_ag_elim
GROUP BY fk_proddes_id, fk_id_cod_deseu
```

the result is:

```
FK_PRODDES_ID   FK_ID_COD_DESEU COD_ELIMINARE
53              112             D 7,D 11
301             506             D 15,D 1
```

But I need D1,D15 and D11,D7. What's wrong with the second query?  Why do I "lose" D1 ???

Thanks!

Comment: What is `unique_list` in your code? Do you have to use it or you need any way to make distinct values?

Comment: just distinct values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways: first - using `regexp_replace` like here - [Eliminate duplicates in ListAgg (Oracle)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/696/eliminate-duplicates-in-listagg-oracle), second - use `distinct` inside a subquery:

```
select fk_proddes_id,fk_id_cod_deseu, 
       listagg(to_char(cod_eliminare), ',') within group (order by cod_eliminare desc)
  from (select distinct fk_proddes_id,fk_id_cod_deseu, cod_eliminare
          from sim_sd.proddes_ag_elim)
 group by fk_proddes_id, fk_id_cod_deseu
```